# Deprecated Warning: Why won't my Matrix print?

Tags: python, matrix, printing, deprecated

So I am doing a little project for my linear algebra class and I wanted to make a program that could construct an i by j matrix and then do a Row Echelon form-esque algorithm. But before any of that I wanted python to print a matrix before it performed the task so you could see the original matrix. This is what I have for code.

```
import math
import numpy
i = eval(input("how many rows? "))
j = eval(input("how many columns? "))
def make_matrix(i,j):
     matrix = numpy.random.random_integerers(0,100,(i,j))
print(make_matrix(i,j))
```

So then I get this message:

C:\Users\Schmidt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__main__.py:2: DeprecationWarning: This function is deprecated. Please call randint(0, 100 + 1) instead
  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app

and now do not know what to do. Could someone explain to me what is happening and guide me to a solution?

Comment: That is just a warning about a function that will be removed *in future* versions. It has no other impact than the message at the moment.

Comment: so how would i go about printing the matrix then?

Comment: It's `numpy.random.random_integers`, not `numpy.random.random_integerers`.

Comment: that's rather embarrassing that i didn't see that one earlier :| sorry

Answer (score 0):

The solution was so easy as to write a return in the define fuction

```
def make_matrix(i,j):
    matrix = numpy.random.randint(0,50,(i,j))
    return(matrix)
print(make_matrix(i,j))
```